# insertar varios arreglos con php

Tags: php

Como puedo insertar varios arreglos en mysql con php.

**html**

```
<form action="">
  <input type="text" name="producto[]">
  <input type="text" name="precio[]">
  <input type="text" name="cantidad[]">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**php**

```
$arrayproducto=$_POST['producto'];
$arraycantidad=$_POST['cantidad'];

$arrayprecio=$_POST['precio'];

$combinar=array_combine($arrayproducto, $arraycantidad);

foreach($combinar as $producto=>$cantidad)
{
 // Consulta para insertar los arreglos
}
```

Usualmente insertaba de esa forma dos arreglos, pero ahora que tengo otro array (**$arrayprecio**), como puedo insertar el tercero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que tienes en esos `$_POST` usan la misma llave:

```
$arrayproducto=$_POST['producto'];
$arraycantidad=$_POST['cantidad'];
$arrayprecio=$_POST['precio'];
foreach($arrayproducto as $llave=>$producto){
  $array_final[$producto] = [
    'cantidad'=>$arraycantidad[$llave], 
    'precio'=>$arrayprecio[$llave] 
  ];
}

print_r($array_final);
```

Para armar tus queries SQL sería algo así:

```
foreach($array_final as $producto=>$detalle){
  $sql="INSERT INTO tbl_detalle_venta (prod_id, cantidad, precio) VALUES ('$producto','$detalle[cantidad]','$detalle[precio]')";
}
```

Si no usan la misma llave necesitaríamos un ejemplo del contenido de esos `$_POST`, sugiero intentes este código.

Comment: Te agradezco tanto #Solrac. Gracias. Que Dios te de buena vida y mucha Salud, no dejes de compartir jamas tus conocimientos.

Comment: Me da gusto poder ayudar @JMZAlexander, si te sirve la respuesta puedes dar un upvote con la flecha hacia arriba. Gracias por el comentario y los buenos deseos; son recíprocos!